# To what extent can ImageMagick retain a clipping path when converting PSD files into GIF, PNG, JPG files?

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, image-clipping

We have a PHP tool which converts images **from PSD into other formats** by calling **ImageMagick**.

In order to potentially extend the tool's functionality, I now need to find out "**what are the possibilities of ImageMagick to convert PSD files into GIF, PNG, and JPG files in respect to clipping paths**", e.g. answering the following questions:

- can ImageMagick convert PSD files into GIF/JPG/PNG and **maintain the clipping path** so that it can be further edited later?
- or can ImageMagick only convert PSD files into GIF/JPG/PNG and therefore **converting everything outside the clipping path** into a **transparent area**?
- do each of the formats GIF, PNG, and JPG **even support clipping paths** in the sense that PSD files support them?

Comment: Did you notice bonzo's answer at all? Did it not help you with your problem?

Comment: You're strange animal... Asking (good) questions here, but then not react to (good) answers or (any) comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not have a psd file with a clip path - out of interest could you provide me with one I can use on my imagemagick example site? I have a jpg with a clip path but am not alowed to use it on my site.

Anyway I started with a jpg that I am told has a clip path and ran this code:

```
exec(" convert clip_path.jpg -clip -negate clipped1.jpg");
exec(" convert clip_path.jpg -resize x300 -clip -negate clipped2.jpg");
exec(" convert clip_path.jpg clipped3.png");
exec(" convert clipped3.png -clip -negate clipped4.jpg");
```

The results were:

1/ Inverted colours within the clip path - so clip path is working.

2/ Resized and inverted colours within the clip path - so clip path is retained on resize.

3/ Changed to a png ready for the clip test in 4/

4/ Inverted colours within the clip path - clip path is retaind when changing format.

The clip options are listed here http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clip and some examples and more notes here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#clip_mask

Comment: Not even a comment to my post - I give up with this site.

Comment: You're a true ImageMagician! I only started to follow your answers here today -- but I found a few true gems already. Please don't give up!  :-)